# Pointer comparison crashing my program

Tags: pointers, crash

I have a line of code that is crashing my program in release mode, but not in debug mode...

```
if((DWORD)pPrev < (DWORD)pBlock && pPrev->pList == &gFreeList)
```

I cast to DWORD to compare the addresses of the pointers... In this if-block, the previous node will accumulate the current node, but only if its physical address is lower than the current block and it is free already... The block code is not the problem. It won't even enter the block. It crashes during the comparison of the pointers.

The code works perfectly in debug mode, so I can't get it to crash or even malfunction in debug mode for me to see what is going on... I don't see what's wrong with this. Any ideas?

If it helps, I am using VC6 for prototype development (simply because the IDE is less resource-intensive)...

Thanks

Comment: You know, VC6 is notorious for being incredibly buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't `pPrev` be not initialized?

If so, the precondition, `(DWORD)pPrev < (DWORD)pBlock` can not hold in debug mode because unitialized `pPrev` is set to `0xCCCCCCCC`  (or `CD`?), that will be surely larger than any pointer casted to DWORD (2, at most 3GBs in 32bit mode -> max userspace address `0xBFFFFFFF`).

However, in release mode it would contain any garbage, so it could be dereferenced in `(DWORD)pPrev < (DWORD)pBlock` and crash the program.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison should not be causing problems here. In fact, I think the comparison would work even without the casts to DWORD. I would suspect that it's pPrev->pList that's causing the problem. Are you sure pPrev has not been freed by accident before the dereference?

Comment: I'll go thru it again to see, but pPrev wasn't even referenced before this point... and in debug mode, just before it would crash in release mode, the pPrev pointer is fine... I just wish I could get it to crash in debug mode.

Comment: It runs fine when compiled with VS2008 in release mode... I give up on VC6. The only thing I can think of is some kind of optimization bug

Comment: Have you tried tracing of all variables involved, e.g. using printf(), just before the problematic line, while running in Release mode?